# Query to select appropriate row and calculate elapsed time

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need some help in coming up with a query that will return the answer to the question “How long has a Help Desk Ticket been owned by the currently assigned group?”  Following is a subset of the data model with some sample data:

**Help Desk Cases**

```
Case ID (PK)    Assigned Person    Assigned Group
123456             Robert            Hardware
```

**Help Desk Case Assignment History**

```
Case ID (PK)    Seq # (PK)    Assigned Group    Assigned Person    Elapsed Time    Row Added Date/Time
123456            1             Hardware                             10 
123456            2             Software                              2 
123456            3             Hardware              Sam             1 
123456            4             Software              Sophie          6 
123456            5             Hardware                              8 
123456            6             Hardware              Sam             3 
123456            7             Hardware              Robert
```

The Elapsed Time column for the most recent row (Seq #7) is not updated until a subsequent row (Seq #8) is written, so I don’t think I can use an aggregate function.  For the sample data above, I need to get the Row Added column from Seq # 5 and subtract it from the current date to get the total amount of time the case has been most recently assigned to the Hardware group (we ignore previous assignments such as Seq # 1 and Seq # 3).

The Query output for the example above should be:

```
Case ID    Assigned Group    Assigned Person    Time Owned
123456       Hardware          Robert            Current Date - Seq #5 Row Added Date/Time
```

Comment: rank will let you know which items are in the most recent group -- then do a group by and min() on the date field

Comment: Maybe I'm not using Rank correctly, but when I try it I get all of the rows for Hardware and so Min gives me Seq #1, when I need Seq # 5

Comment: you need the min to use partition by the rank value or use a group by statement on the result of the rank.

Answer (score 1):

With Oracle 12c and higher...

```
select case_id,
    last_assigned_group as assigned_group,
    last_assigned_person as assigned_person,
    nvl(last_row_added, systimestamp) - first_row_added as time_owned
from help_desk_case_assignment_history
    match_recognize (
        partition by case_id
        order by seq#
        measures
            first(row_added) as first_row_added,
            last(row_added) as last_row_added,
            last(assigned_group) as last_assigned_group,
            last(assigned_person) as last_assigned_person
        one row per match
        after match skip past last row
        pattern (
            assignment_run* case_end
        )
        define
            assignment_run as (assigned_group = next(assigned_group)),
            case_end as (elapsed_time is null or next(assigned_group) is null)
    )
;
```

**In human words:** Per each helpdesk case ID find the last uninterrupted "run" of assignments within the same group. For the last "run" of assignments identify its starting time, ending time, and ending person. And display the found values.

---

With Oracle 11g and lower...

```
with xyz as (
    select X.*,
        case when lnnvl(assigned_group = lag(assigned_group) over (partition by case_id order by seq#)) then seq# end as assignment_run_start
    from help_desk_case_assignment_history X
),
xyz2 as (
    select X.*,
        last_value(assignment_run_start) ignore nulls over (partition by case_id order by seq#) as assignment_run_id
    from xyz X
),
xyz3 as (
    select case_id, assigned_group, assignment_run_id,
        max(assigned_person) keep (dense_rank last order by seq#) as last_assigned_person,
        nvl(max(row_added) keep (dense_rank last order by seq#), systimestamp)
            - min(row_added) keep (dense_rank first order by seq#)
            as time_owned,
        row_number() over (partition by case_id order by assignment_run_id desc) as last_group_ind
    from xyz2 X
    group by case_id, assigned_group, assignment_run_id
)
select case_id, assigned_group, last_assigned_person as assigned_person, time_owned
from xyz3
where last_group_ind = 1
;
```

Perhaps ugly, but pretty straightforward and working.

**In human words:**

1. Identify the boundaries (starts) of assignment runs as increasing numeric IDs.
2. Extend the found assignment run starts to the whole assignment runs.
3. Calculate the assignments' run times and last assigned persons.
4. Restrict the previous calculation to the last (by their ID) assignment run only.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer.  I should have mentioned that we are in the dark ages on 11G, so we can't use the fantastic new match_recognize function.

Comment: @1earldog, answer updated for "ancient" Oracles. :-) Sorry, I could not do it sooner.